# Screen between 6" and 9.7"

Tags: hardware

Are there any ebook readers with electronic paper and screen between 6" and 9.7"? I can find only such with an ordinary laptop-like screen...

Comment: This looks like a shopping question, which is generally discouraged on this site.

Comment: @JamesJenkins It is a long way to shopping. Now it is only searching a proper tool, better than Kindle or Onyx.

Comment: Sony plans to release a 13.3" flexible electronic paper screen ereader...craziness! http://www.gizmag.com/sony-student-ereader-mobius/27489/

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke When James Jenkins calls this [a shopping question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad), he is referring to a type of question that has been identified as not good for this kind of site. It does not mean you are actually shopping

Answer (score 8):

Here are four:

- [Kobo Aura HD](http://www.kobo.com/koboaurahd/techspecs/) (6.8" screen)
- [ICARUS8 e-reader](http://www.icarusreader.com/) (8" screen)
- [Kindle DX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002GYWHSQ) (9.7" screen)
- [Bookeen Cybook Ocean](http://www.bookeen.com/en/cybook-ocean) (8" screen, status 2013-12: announced)